# How to change these tray icons?

Tags: icons, themes, appearance, widgets

I recently customized my ubuntu(Release:22.04,jammy)(GNOME) with the help of candy-icons(https://github.com/EliverLara/candy-icons) and Sweet-Ambar-Blue(https://github.com/EliverLara/Sweet/tree/Ambar-Blue) theme. Everything looks good but I am having a hard time with the widgets at the corner of my [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Ztm.png). They look really bad.

When I click on [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m90yN.png).

**I want to change these tray icons.**

I have searched the `.themes/Sweet-Amber-Blue/` and `.icons/candy-icons/` folders but I couldn't find the icons being displayed(An attempt to replace the image files).
I tried to look for the Icon var under `/usr/share/applications/` too (Example-nm-applet.desktop, brightness-controller.desktop) but I ended up nowhere.

I am relatively new with this customization so if anyone can please help me to change these widgets or comment a link to some github repo that deals with these widgets I'd really appreciate it.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: please [edit] your question with details of your version of ubuntu, DE and how these customisations were performed together with what it is you seek to achieve as that is not clear.

Comment: Those icons are called system tray icons. Use an icon theme that supports it, like Papirus. There is a project that is related to this area https://github.com/bilelmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray

Comment: @24601 I have updated the question, I hope its easier to understand now.

Comment: @user227495 Oh, Ill look into that project.Thanks :)